# WCF Service to expose part of a Web API

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, wcf, dynamics-crm

I have been given the task of creating a WCF Service that exposes only part of a oData REST API. Only certain functionalities allowed by the REST API is supposed to be exposed by the WCF Service. (The WCF Service basically acts as a filter).

What could be my approach for this? I know I can call the WCF service using proxy classes. But those would just be direct method calls. I do not want a separate function for each of the operations. Is there a better way?

Comment: _"I do not want a separate function for each of the operations_" - why?

Comment: Because there could be way too many operations. I'm trying to expose only part of the Dynamics CRM Web API.

Comment: But they would be generated for you in the proxy, and then you just expose the ones you want?

Answer (score 0):

You could choose which operations are exposed through WebApi adding attribute [WebGet] on the operation contract.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet]
string Method2(string s);
```

But if you expose service through net.tcp there is no default way of disabling some for this protocol.

To manage this task you need to write custom behavior which will check what protocol is used and will allow to perform invocation or throw exception.

Start with the custom attribute which define operation which can be executed through chosen channel.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet]
[WcfAllowed]
string Method1(string s);
```

Next we need message inspector which will use our custom attribute. 
Mmessage inspector

- checks for the chosen protocol (net.tcp).
- gets the method name which is invoked
- finds in the interface method
- checks if method is marked with our custom attribute
- if not throws exception

code below:

```
public class DispatchMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        if (channel is IServiceChannel serviceChannel)
        {
            if (serviceChannel.ListenUri.Scheme == "net.tcp")
            {
                string methodName=request.Headers.Action.Split('/').Last();
                TypeInfo serviceType = instanceContext.Host.Description.ServiceType as TypeInfo;
                foreach (var @interface in serviceType.ImplementedInterfaces)
                {
                    var method = @interface.GetMethod(methodName);
                    if (method != null)
                    {
                        var attributes = method.GetCustomAttributes().Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(WcfAllowedAttribute)).FirstOrDefault();
                        if (attributes == null)
                        {
                            throw new OnyWebApiException($"Method which was invoked: {methodName}");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return request;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {

    }
 }
```

Last element to ad is to wire our message inspector with the service. To do this we need service behavior.

```
public class CustomServiceBehavior : Attribute, IServiceBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
       foreach(ChannelDispatcher channelDispatcher in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            foreach (var endpointDispatcher in channelDispatcher.Endpoints)
            {
                endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new DispatchMessageInspector());
            }
        }
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {

    }
}
```

Service behavior needs to be connected to the service. The easiest way is to just mark the service with attribute:

```
[CustomServiceBehavior]
public class CustomService : ICustomContract
{
    public string Method1(string s)
    {
        return s;
    }

    public string Method2(string s)
    {
        return s;
    }
}
```

I created [solution](https://github.com/pwujczyk/ProductivityTools.Examples.WCFAspects) to show it in action. If you are interested please checkout branch **OnlyNetTcp**.